# Grouping Drools Rules in AND/OR groups

Tags: java, drools

I have several domain rules (I'll call them 'preconditions') that I am describing as Drools Rules. For example, for a Student to be considered as `HasGoodGrades`, they must maintain a GPA > 3.0. I also have rules that are basically boolean logic groupings of these preconditions -- such as `IsInHonorRoll`. For `IsInHonorRoll` to be true, the rule `HasGoodGrades` needs to to be satisfied, OR (`HasOkGrades` AND `HasPerfectAttendance`).

How I'm handling this is I'm inserting `PreconditionResult` facts when the rule is satisfied. Then, in these larger 'grouping' rules, I'm checking for these `PreconditionResult` facts and doing the boolean logic there:

```drools
rule "IsInHonorRoll"
      dialect "mvel"
  when
      $s : Student()
      PreconditionResult( id == "HasGoodGrades", student == $s)
      or
      ( PreconditionResult( id == "HasOkGrades", student == $s)
      and
      PreconditionResult( id == "HasPerfectAttendance", student == $s) )
  then
      System.out.print("Student is in the Honor Roll.");

end

rule "HasOkGrades"
      dialect "mvel"
  when
      $s : Student( gpa > 2.0 )
  then
      insert(new PreconditionResult("HasOkGrades", $s))
end

rule "HasGoodGrades"
      dialect "mvel"
  when
      $s : Student( gpa < 3.0 )
  then
      insert(new PreconditionResult("HasGoodGrades", $s))
end

rule "HasPerfectAttendance"
      dialect "mvel"
  when
      $s : Student( daysAbsent == 0 )
  then
      insert(new PreconditionResult("HasPerfectAttendance", $s))
end
```

This seems to work, but feels unnatural, and I'm sure there is a better way to do this type of thing within Drools. More importantly, given enough of these rules and large and complex enough boolean clauses, Drools starts dying with Out of Memory errors, even given very large heap sizes.

What is the best way to handle these boolean logic 'groupings' of Drools Rules? Thanks!

Comment: did you find any resolution for this?

Answer (score 0):

More natural way of reusing preconditions in drools is DSL. You can then combine as complex logical statements as you need. For example

```
rule Test2
  when
    There is a ShoppingCart that 
    - worth a discount
  then
    print eligible price
end
```

DSL

```
[when]worth a discount = 
    (total price is not less than 500
    and not over limit
    or total price is greater than 5000)
// stupid condition just for demonstration
[when]over limit = ((total price + total price * 0.05) > total price + 50)
[when]total price = totalPrice
```

Check full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60694923/448078)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, this is the Drools way (take babysteps - each step is its own rule). Just split the first rule into two separate rules so that you won't need any OR.

There are different strategys to avoid large memory usage. One idea is to insert only data of a single student into session, run it and then create new session for next student and run all the rules again. Other strategys exists besides this one.